# How to make split listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Hello everyone first of all me english is bad , so i will do my best to devliver what i want to do in my listview.

anyway i have a listview , i need to split into two sides. (left - right) like this image an example -----> https://ibb.co/dotxS5

this is my layout code.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.tasneem.coustomlistview.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my row-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/name"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="name"
      android:textSize="25dp"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Image"
      android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Image"
      android:layout_marginStart="38dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I just want to do the above following in layouts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) instead of ListView.

With RecyclerView you can easily create a grid with [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html).

```
myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, numberOfColumns);
myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: brother can u help me?

Comment: brother can u help me.?  I did the same thing in GridLayoutManager and it works good.   But how to so it in staggerLayout?  I did it with staggerLayout and the images appears same as Grid nothing different.